# Can I block certain MAC addresses from a cyberoam firewalls DHCP server?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, dhcp-server

Is there a way to "tell" cyberoams DHCP server not to serve specific MAC addresses? for instance if it sees a DHCP request from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff it should not reply to that request but it should reply to all others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DHCP** is designed to lease an **IP address** for the host which is looking for it. Hence blacklisting this is not possible as per the vendor UI design.

Instead you can fool your machine which has the **MAC address** ***aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff*** by creating a static lease with the host MAC address and pointing to **quad zero** IP address.

[image]